# How can I change the meta key on OS X Lion's Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there any way to use "Option" as the meta key in OS X Lion's Terminal.app? The checkbox that was present in Snow Leopard is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that it's not to be found?  If I look at Preferences → Settings → Keyboard, the checkbox for Use option as meta key is at the bottom.

I am on 10.7.1 so it *may* be something overlooked in the GM of Lion and fixed in the first patch.

Comment: Nope, you're 100% right. No idea how I missed it...

Answer (score 1):

I came here an hour ago with the same question and now I feel the answer need to be better elaborated. So:

1. Open the Terminal. The terminal menu should appear near to the apple icon.
2. Click `Terminal --> Preferences...` The settings dialog box should pop up.
3. Click the `Settings` tab on upper left side of the dialog box, then you should be able to choose the `Keyboard` button.

The `Use Option as meta key` check box should be visible on the lower border by the center. And you are done.